firebase firestore: "error": "Missing or insufficient permissions."
I keep getting this error even though i have already set rules that allow reading of data like this:
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
        allow get, create, update, delete: if true;
    }
}

here's how i get the data:
getAllByConstraint(p_field, p_constraint) {
        return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                const db = getFirestore()
                const request = query(collection(db, 'report'), 
                                where(p_field, '==', p_constraint))

                const snapshot = await getDocs(request)
                console.log("constraint" + p_constraint)

                if (!snapshot.empty) {
                    const results = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
                    resolve(results);
                } else {
                    throw new Error(`Fetching failed. No information found.`)
                }
            } 
            catch(error) { reject(error) }
        })
    }```


update your firebase rule
rules_version = '2';

  service cloud.firestore {

    match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
        allow read, create, update, delete: if true;
    }
}

So use read instead of get, so that it also covers list operations/queries.
